# Data analysis formula for the given snapshot

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have some data in excel which I forwarded to someone. What I received as a snapshot in the response looked like they used some formula to define a hierarchy based on parent-child relationship.

[image: Before and After snapshot]

Could somebody please help in identifying what they did?

The way the cells look post what they did is not something I have ever seen or could find on Google.

Comment: It looks like they have used the grouping functionality on the data tab. Have you tried asking them?

Comment: I tried grouping. But what happens is it becomes more of a visibility thing rather than hierarchy thing. Also, its more of an amusing secret for them.